# type issues when using a golang library

Tags: go

I have a project that is vendoring golang.org/x/text libraries. My directory structure looks like:

```
projectname/
    server/
        localization.go

    vendor/
        golang.org
            x/
                text/
                    language/
                    message/
                    internal/
                    currency/
                    ...
```

Within `localization.go` I'm trying to use `message` library in this way:

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
    "golang.org/x/text/message"
)

func formatCurrency() string {
    p := message.NewPrinter(language.BrazilianPortuguese)
    // do something with p
    return "placeholder"
}
```

However this is failing to compile with the error:

```
Building... 
# github.com/orgname/projectname/vendor/golang.org/x/text/internal/number
../../vendor/golang.org/x/text/internal/number/number.go:150:41: cannot convert t (type 
"github.com/orgname/projectname/vendor/golang.org/x/text/language".Tag) to type compact.Tag

2018/06/05 18:17:26 compile failed:  [] exit status 2

make: *** [all] Error 1
```

`vendor/golang.org/x/text/internal/number/number.go` has its imports like:

```
import (
    "unicode/utf8"

    "golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)
```

I'm stuck on why number.go is having a type issue since all the libraries necessary are in the vendor directory and how to resolve it. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Make sure _all_ your dependencies are vendored in a single vendor directory for the project.

Comment: @Isha make sure that your vendor folder also contains the `golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact` package.

Comment: Did you get it fixed?

Comment: @jaede yes. The issue was that I had the `golang.org/x/text/internal/language/compact` (and some others) already vendored but I had older versions. Trying to vendor the localization packages was bringing in new versions which were incompatible with the existing packages I had.